# Magneto error to move all fiels local to live and got the error

Tags: php, access-denied

I have create sub domain in server then move all files local to sub-domain folder 
- root folder one magneto is already working.
- How to solve this error

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Trace:

## 0 /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

## 1 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_sluglib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()

## 2 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_sluglib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()

## 3 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_sluglib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)

## 4 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_sluglib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)

## 5 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')

## 6 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))

## 7 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(861): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')

## 8 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/local/Amasty/Fpc/Model/Fpc/Front.php(97): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->getDbConfig('web/url/use_sto...')

## 9 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(703): Amasty_Fpc_Model_Fpc_Front->__construct()

## 10 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_getProcessor('Amasty_Fpc_Mode...')

## 11 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->processRequest()

## 12 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugapp/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 13 /home/public_html/rest_manager_list_slugindex.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 14 {main}

Comment: Did you update your database details?

Comment: yes update database base url and changes in local.xml